# Mongo Scala Driver 2.1 - case class error

Tags: mongodb, mongo-scala-driver

This is my first time working with the Mongo Scala driver (version 2.1) and I am noticing odd behavior in the handling of some of my case classes -- some of them are not being recognized as such in the `classToCaseClassMap` with the result that decoding data for one of them goes down the wrong path and ends with the error `java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list` at line 204 in `org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.macrocodecs.MacroCodec` because the `fieldClazzTypeArgs` list is empty.

Here is the top third or so of the stacktrace:

```
error: class java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:420)
scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:417)
org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.macrocodecs.MacroCodec$class.readDocument(MacroCodec.scala:204)
palladium.calendar.dal.mongodb.Implicits$$anon$2$GoogleCalendarEventMacroCodec$3.readDocument(GoogleCalendarDAO.scala:55)
org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.macrocodecs.MacroCodec$class.readValue(MacroCodec.scala:173)
palladium.calendar.dal.mongodb.Implicits$$anon$2$GoogleCalendarEventMacroCodec$3.readValue(GoogleCalendarDAO.scala:55)
org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.macrocodecs.MacroCodec$class.decode(MacroCodec.scala:104)
palladium.calendar.dal.mongodb.Implicits$$anon$2$GoogleCalendarEventMacroCodec$3.decode(GoogleCalendarDAO.scala:55)
org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.macrocodecs.MacroCodec$class.readDocument(MacroCodec.scala:197)
palladium.calendar.dal.mongodb.Implicits$$anon$8$GoogleCalendarMacroCodec$3.readDocument(GoogleCalendarDAO.scala:61)
org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.macrocodecs.MacroCodec$class.readValue(MacroCodec.scala:173)
palladium.calendar.dal.mongodb.Implicits$$anon$8$GoogleCalendarMacroCodec$3.readValue(GoogleCalendarDAO.scala:61)
org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.macrocodecs.MacroCodec$class.readArray(MacroCodec.scala:187)
palladium.calendar.dal.mongodb.Implicits$$anon$8$GoogleCalendarMacroCodec$3.readArray(GoogleCalendarDAO.scala:61)
org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.macrocodecs.MacroCodec$class.readValue(MacroCodec.scala:174)
palladium.calendar.dal.mongodb.Implicits$$anon$8$GoogleCalendarMacroCodec$3.readValue(GoogleCalendarDAO.scala:61)
org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.macrocodecs.MacroCodec$class.decode(MacroCodec.scala:104)
palladium.calendar.dal.mongodb.Implicits$$anon$8$GoogleCalendarMacroCodec$3.decode(GoogleCalendarDAO.scala:61)
com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultArrayCodec.decode(CommandResultArrayCodec.java:52)
com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultDocumentCodec.readValue(CommandResultDocumentCodec.java:53)
org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84)
org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
org.bson.codecs.configuration.LazyCodec.decode(LazyCodec.java:47)
org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.readValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:101)
com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultDocumentCodec.readValue(CommandResultDocumentCodec.java:56)
org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84)
org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
com.mongodb.connection.ReplyMessage.<init>(ReplyMessage.java:57)
com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.getResponseDocument(CommandProtocol.java:139)
com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.access$000(CommandProtocol.java:51)
com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol$CommandResultCallback.callCallback(CommandProtocol.java:271)
com.mongodb.connection.ResponseCallback.onResult(ResponseCallback.java:48)
com.mongodb.connection.ResponseCallback.onResult(ResponseCallback.java:23)
com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$2.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:470)
com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$2.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:464)
com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$3.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:119)
com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$3.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:115)
com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.executeCallbackAndReceiveResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:378)
com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$1700(InternalStreamConnection.java:66)
com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseBuffersCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:420)
com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseBuffersCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:389)
com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseHeaderCallback.onSuccess(InternalStreamConnection.java:562)
com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseHeaderCallback.access$2200(InternalStreamConnection.java:517)
com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseHeaderCallback$ResponseBodyCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:584)
com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseHeaderCallback$ResponseBodyCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:568)
com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$3.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:447)
com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$3.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:444)
com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:218)
com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:201)
sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:157)
sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:553)
sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:276)
sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:297)
```

My application models someone's Google calendar. Here are my case classes:

```
case class GoogleDateTime(date: Option[DateTime] = None, dateTime: Option[DateTime])

case class LongId(id: Long)

case class GoogleCalendarEvent(id: String,
                           status: Option[String] = None,
                           htmlLink: Option[String] = None,
                           created: Option[DateTime] = None,
                           updated: Option[DateTime] = None,
                           creator: Option[GoogleWho] = None,
                           organizer: Option[GoogleWho] = None,
                           summary: Option[String],
                           description: Option[String] = None,
                           location: Option[String] = None,
                           start: GoogleDateTime,
                           end: GoogleDateTime,
                           extendedProperties: Option[GoogleEventExtendedProperties] = None)

case class GoogleCalendarEventList(nextPageToken: Option[String],
                               items: Option[List[GoogleCalendarEvent]])

case class GoogleWho(email: Option[String],
                 displayName: Option[String])

case class GoogleEventSharedProperties(createdBy: Option[String] = None,
                                   sessionType: Option[String] = None,
                                   sessionId: Option[LongId] = None,
                                   locationId: Option[LongId] = None,
                                   roomId: Option[LongId] = None)

case class GoogleEventExtendedProperties(shared: Option[GoogleEventSharedProperties])
```

[Here is a link to a screenshot showing the contents of the `classToCaseClassMap`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6DOoMull5teZU9MMEpEdUp3WXc/view?usp=sharing) at the point where the error occurs.

The screenshot shows a map with six items, including four of my case classes: `GoogleCalendarEvent`, `GoogleWho`, `GoogleDateTime`, and `GoogleEventExtendedProperties`. Only the first of these (`GoogleCalendarEvent`) is properly identified as a case class.

I tried making the problematic classes `sealed` but that didn't help.

Here is how I create the CodecRegistry:

```
val dtMap = Map(BsonType.DATE_TIME -> classOf[DateTime])

val typeClassReplacedMap = new BsonTypeClassMap(JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(dtMap))

val gcCodecProvider = new DocumentCodecProvider(typeClassReplacedMap)

implicit val gcRegistry: CodecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromCodecs(dtCodec),
fromProviders( gcCodecProvider,
classOf[GoogleCalendarEvent],
classOf[GoogleDateTime],
classOf[LongId],
classOf[GoogleEventExtendedProperties],
classOf[GoogleEventSharedProperties],
classOf[GoogleWho],
classOf[GoogleCalendar]),
DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY )
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/kmdoherty/ec4b1e1e05707141e8e612100c81479f) is a gist showing the data access code and how I am using it (in an sbt console or Intellij IDEA Scala console).

The app I am refactoring has been working fine with the Reactive Mongo version 0.11.7 but we need to migrate it to the officially supported Mongo Scala driver in order to use a new Atlas database.

Comment: Hi "some of them are not being recognized" which of them are not recognised. Can you post the snippet of you code where you are using them in relation with mongoDB driver? Stack trace of the exception will be helpful too.

Comment: Maybe I added this after you read my post (sorry, I keep adding to it). The image would have shown a map with six items, including four of my case classes: GoogleCalendarEvent, GoogleWho, GoogleDateTime, and GoogleEventExtendedProperties. Only the first of these (GoogleCalendarEvent) is properly identified as a case class.

Comment: I added as much of the stacktrace as i could work with (the top third or so)

Comment: How do you know that GoogleCalendarEvent is properly identified? Stacktrace seems to be already related to reading response from MongoDB, can you post the snippet with operation to MongoDB?

Comment: Hi @Teliatko I couldn't include an image showing the contents of the `classToCaseClassMap` but [here is a link to it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6DOoMull5teZU9MMEpEdUp3WXc/view?usp=sharing). Hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed similar problem with reordering fromProviders items.
Those guys class A(b: B) and class B(i: Int) should be in reverse order:
fromProviders(classOf[B], classOf[A])

So, looks like you should place classOf[GoogleCalendarEvent] after classOf[GoogleEventExtendedProperties]

Comment: I spent hours on it. It really does the trick. Thank you guy.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW after that time, have a look at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SCALA-338

I have the same issue, thanks to your post I found out that it's somehow the ordering of the codec providers.

Initially I though it could be solved by making sure that case classes that hold values of other case class types are listed before these other cases classes. But by now even that did not solve my issue anymore, but maybe it can help solve your specific situation.

Simply downgrading from 2.1.0 to 2.0.0 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: downgrading worked for me, changing the order did not help.